# SQL query to identify rows not contained contained in another table across multiple subsets

Tags: sql

I have two tables as seen below.

Table 1:

```
Day Group
---------
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   B
2   C
2   D
3   C
3   D
3   E
```

Table 2:

```
Group
-------
A
B
C
D
E
```

I would like to create a SQL query that identifies each Group that exists in Table 2 but does not exist in Table 1 partitioned by Day.

The desired result would look like this:

```
Day Group
---------
1   D
1   E
2   A
2   E
3   A
3   B
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate all combinations and then weed out what you have:

```
select d.day, t1.group
from (select distinct day from table1) d cross join
     table2 g left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.day = d.day and t1.group = g.group
where t1.day is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            Day
        FROM
            Table1
    ) AS Days
    ,
    Table2
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            Table1
        WHERE
            Table1.day=Days.Day AND
            Table1.Group=Table2.Group
    )
```